# change param in request of Slim Framework 3

Tags: slim-3

Using Slim 3 Framework I try to change a param of a post/put-request in one function and pass the manipulated request to another function like this:

```
public function myFunction(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
    $markdown = $request->getParams("markdown");
    $markdown = strg_replace('needle', 'replace', $markdown);
    $request->setParams("markdown", $markdown);
    $this->anotherFunction($request, $response, $args);
}
```

Of course, `setParams` does not exist in slim, so I tried with getAttribute / withAttribute, but it seems that you do not have access to the post/put-params like this:

```
    $markdown = $request->getAttribute('markdown'); // is empty
    $markdown = strg_replace('needle', 'replace', $markdown);
    $request = $request->withAttribute('markdown', $markdown);
    $this->anotherFunction($request, $response, $args);
```

I found another function `withParsedBody()` but I don't see a way to manipulate the params and put it back into the request and pass the request. Has anybody an idea or an workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, I just found it in the documentation of [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/):

```
$params = $request->getParsedBody();
$params['markdown'] = 'manipulate me'
$request = $request->withParsedBody($params);
```

and that works. Maybe it helps someone...